# @Transactional take old values on not committed transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-transactions

I'm writing a `@Transactional` method that

1. updates an entity (Service1.update)
2. call another `@Transactional` method in another service that make some calculation (involving also the current updated entity) (Service2.calculate)

My problem is that in the point 2, I make a select that involves also the current updated entity. The outer transaction is not committed yet and the select load the old entity values. So the calculus are based on old values.

```
class Service1{

    @Autowired
    private Service2 service2;

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public update(final Entry entry) {

        repository.save(entry);
        // already tried to flush session injecting entityManager 
        //or to call saveAndFlush, but it doesn't works!

        service2.calculate(entry.getContainer());
    }
}

class Service2{

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public calculate(final Container entry) {
        //do the job: calculate the sum of the power of each entity grouper by category
        List<Report> report = calcRepository.calculate(entry);

        //here the report is filled with sum composed also by the of old value of current entity

    }
}


class CalcRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository{
    @Query("select new Report(" +
            "a.type, " +
            "a.combust, "+
            "a.container.id, "+
            "sum(a.power)) "+
            "from Entry a " +
            "where ..... " +
            "group by a.type, a.combust")
    List<Report> calculate(@Param("container") Container container);
}
```

I'm doing that select in order to get grouped values for current container: every time I modify an entity I must recalculate values of its container.

How can I solve this issue? Thank you

Comment: How and why are you doing that select? If it's a native query then the result *should* be the old data

Comment: why you just not flush the first method so selects should be visible to the second one?

Comment: another thing is that this is not an outer transaction ... this is still the same one as far as you have not overriden the default @Transactional behaviour

Comment: Thank you @Ordus for your comment. I've updated my question: it's not a native query.. it's a jpa query. I'm doing that select because every time I modify an entity I must recalculate values of its container.

Comment: Thank you @MarekRaszewski for your comment! I have updated my question! I have already tried to flush session injecting entityManager or to call saveAndFlush, but it doesn't works!

Comment: @MarekRaszewski I have also tryed to change the propagation behaviour, putting REQUIRES_NEW into Service2.. but still don't works.

Comment: @gipinani Using @Requires_new won't help for the simple reason that your old transaction **has not finished yet**. Now I imagine the `Report` class is **not** a managed entity? If it isn't, then *the query you specified is in fact native*.

Comment: @Ordous no, It is not a managed entity.. It is a DTO, but query is in jpql.. So if it is an equivalent native query.. how can I solve or try to solve it :)?

Comment: @gipinani As far as I know, Hibernate does not support HQL/JPQL queries for non-managed entities. It allows you to write very look-alike queries and supports JDBC params and named params, but they are still native.

Comment: @Ordous So In that base I need to commit outer transaction before.. but if something fails in inner transaction no rollback is possible for the outer.. is that so? Thank you!

Comment: @gipinani Well I see 3 options - commit transaction, report in Java or make Report an entity. I'll put in some details in an answer in some 30-45 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that:

- You modify one of your entities in a transaction
- You *do not commit* the transaction
- You need to recalculate some report that depends on this entity

Since the report is not a managed entity, Hibernate uses a native query to fetch it. That means it is evaluated against the *actual data* in the DB, not modified entity data. And since you have not committed your transaction yet, the modified data is not in the DB yet.

As far as I can see, you have several options available:

- Flush your transaction. Judging by Hibernate docs this should sync the DB and entities without committing.
- If your report is not very complex, you may want to simply amend it for the changed data (E.G. if it's an average over a field, add the diff of the change you made over the entity count)
- Make your `Report` a managed entity. (Not always possible)
- Calculate your report in Java rather than SQL.
- Screw Hibernate and use your own transactions. Then you don't need to commit to read new data.
- Break down your transaction into sub-transactions, committing each one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. First option not works: calling entityManager.flush() nothing change, also with saveAndFlush nothing change. The last one is that one that seems to me more appropriate. How can I split it in sub-strnasaction? And is calculate fails, also entity modify is rolled back? Thank you

Comment: @gipinani By subtransactions I meant that you would be using multiple transactions, so no rollback possible

Comment: @gipinani If flushing does not work, I wonder if you have a non-standard transaction propagation setting? If you try both `flush()` AND transaction `REQUIRES_NEW` (one of the things you mentioned in the comments) it will **not** work

Comment: Yes @Ordus, that was the problem.. damned REQUIRES_NEW. Changed it tu REQUIRED and flushing now works!

Comment: @Ordus.. one last thing if you have patience: this method don't works if I delete an entity and then remake calculation. 
1)delete entity
2)flush
3)make calculus

Results in a transaction lock timeout

Have you got some hints?

Answer (score 2):

Add `Propagation` and `Flush` to your services:

class Service1{

```
    @Autowired
    private Service2 service2;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public update(final Entry entry) {

        repository.saveAndFlsuh(entry);
        // already tried to flush session injecting entityManager 
        //or to call saveAndFlush, but it doesn't works!

        service2.calculate(entry.getContainer());
    }
}

class Service2{

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public calculate(final Container entry) {
        //do the job: calculate the sum of the power of each entity grouper by category
        List<Report> report = calcRepository.calculate(entry);

        //here the report is filled with sum composed also by the of old value of current entity

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works on create/update, but don't works if I delete an entity and then remake calculation. 1)delete entity 2)flush 3)make calculus Results in a transaction lock timeout Have you got some hints?

Comment: @gipinani  what is the type of propagation on the delete method?

Comment: @ShadowEay please forget my comment: it's due to a REQUIRES_NEW into another inner transaction. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @ShadowEay I'd give you another +1.. but I can't :)!

Comment: @gipinani ya I know  xD, and it is ShadowRay not ShadowEay :)